# Construct some explicit bijective functions

Tags: functions

Construct explicit bijective functions such that:

1. $f:[0,1)→[0,∞)$
2. $g:[a,b)→(c,d]$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$
3. $h:[0,1]→[0,1)$ (this isn't possible with a continuous function)

And than you have to explain how you got this function.

I have got the last one:
$$h(x) = \begin{cases}
g(x) & \text{for } x \neq 0, \\
0 & \text{for } x = 0.
\end{cases}$$
where
$$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/(n+1) & \text{for } x = 1/n, n\in\mathbb{N}, \\
x & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
I don't know how to get the other ones and how to explain the last one.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Intriguingly, the last one is the trickiest. And while you have used the essential trick, you didn't do it completely right.

b) should be rather trivial, just let $g(x)=d-\frac{d-c}{b-a}\cdot(x-a)$.

For a) one can take something like $f(x)=\tan (\frac \pi2 x)$ or alternatively, 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=0\\\frac1x-1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

The trick with c) i sthat we want to get rid of the one endpoint $1$, so we might want to leave most points fixed and move $1$ to $\frac12$. Howevre, this implies we cannot leave $\frac12$ fixed and have to move it aways, say to $\frac13$. And so on. Explicitly
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{n+1}&\text{if } x=\frac1n,n\in\mathbb N\\
x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I recommend you lookup "Hilbert's hotel".

In all cases above you should take a moment to check the necessary properties. That is, to show that $\phi\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, you need to show that

- for each $x\in X$, the value $\phi(x)$ is indeed $\in Y$
- $\phi$ is onto, that is for each $y\in Y$ we can exhibit some $x$ with $\phi(x)=y$
- $\phi$ is 1-to-1, that is if $\phi(x_1)=\phi(x_2)$ for $x_1,x_2\in X$ then $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen, that looks great, but how did you get the first two functions?