# Can construct a bijection between R - Q and ( (R - Q) ∩ [0,1] )?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I've tried to show that:

$$[0,1]\sim([0,1] ∩R-Q)$$
I know from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1264245/831100) :
$$[0,1]\sim R-Q$$
But how to construct a bijection between R-Q and $([0,1]∩R-Q)$ ?

I think the function would be like $f:R-Q→[0,1]∩R-Q$:
$$f(x) = \cases{ 1/x & \text{if $  ~x∈(R-Q)-[0,1]$} \\ x & \text{if $~x ∈ (0,1)$} }$$
But I think this function is not complete ... could someone help me please to improve this?

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, not the quotient of $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @StefanOctavian Thanks edited.

Comment: your function is not bijective because, for example, $f(\pi)=f\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}$. I don't think there is a simple way to improve your function to make it bijective without making a completely different one.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(r_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Let $(l_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of irrational numbers of $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, for example, we could define $l_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_n}}$ where $p_n$ is the $n-th$ prime number.

Then, define $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as: $$f(x):=\begin{cases}
l_{2n} &\text{ if } x=l_n\\
l_{2n+1} &\text{ if } x=r_n \\
x &\text{ in other case}
\end{cases}$$
$f$ is a bijection.

Comment: Thanks! But how to prove thats bijection (surjective + injective) ?

Comment: I've proved thats a injection but stucked in surjection.

Comment: Let $y\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. If $y\neq l_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $f(y)=y$. If $y=l_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then, if $n$ is even $f\left(l_{\frac{n}{2}}\right)=l_n$; if $n$ is odd, $f\left(r_{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)=l_n$.